# CWM Superuser on HTC Droid Incredible

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, root-access, superuser

I am trying to install ClockworkMod's Superuser on an HTC Droid Incredible running an older leaked Gingerbread build from Verizon labled TMartin GingerInc. I keep getting the following error:`There was an error installing Superuser. Please send a log of the error to the developer.`.I cannot, however, find a log to send. ChainsDD Superuser and SuperSU lock up often.

Comment: Pretty sure you should only have one superuser running at a time. You aren't trying to run more than one at a time are you?

Comment: @Zooks64: No, I plan on removing my current Superuser once this one is installed.

Comment: I believe you have to remove it BEFORE installing another one.

Comment: @Zooks64: Hmm...Didn't know that. Will try removing normal su first. Sounds reasonable, since neither the normal install nor the recovery install worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after accidentaly deleting my su binary, I downloaded and flashed the zip from http://download.clockworkmod.com/superuser/superuser.zip.